# Python How do i filter out multiple strings from a big string then put it in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, filter

So i have this piece of code here:

```
    Outlook='https://www.myfxbook.com/api/get-community-outlook.json?session=' + session_id
    Outlook_response = requests.get(Outlook, verify = False)
    Outlook_data = Outlook_response.json()['symbols']
```

I get everything i want from here but so i can f.write i need to put it into a string
`lstr = ' '.join(map(str, Outlook_data))`

So now im just left with this:

```
{'name': 'EURUSD', 'shortPercentage': 19, 'longPercentage': 81, 'shortVolume': 5241.27, 'longVolume': 22432.81, 'longPositions': 50708, 'shortPositions': 17864, 'totalPositions': 68572, 'avgShortPrice': 1.0925, 'avgLongPrice': 1.1103} {'name': 'GBPUSD', 'shortPercentage': 20, 'longPercentage': 80, 'shortVolume': 2319.04, 'longVolume': 9272.55, 'longPositions': 28637, 'shortPositions': 8572, 'totalPositions': 37209, 'avgShortPrice': 1.3014, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3248} {'name': 'USDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 79, 'longPercentage': 21, 'shortVolume': 13172.25, 'longVolume': 3475.09, 'longPositions': 4530, 'shortPositions': 23878, 'totalPositions': 28408, 'avgShortPrice': 118.2402, 'avgLongPrice': 122.0914} {'name': 'GBPJPY', 'shortPercentage': 78, 'longPercentage': 22, 'shortVolume': 1476.39, 'longVolume': 421.39, 'longPositions': 1820, 'shortPositions': 5248, 'totalPositions': 7068, 'avgShortPrice': 155.8968, 'avgLongPrice': 160.6128} etc.
```

My problem is that i need to filter out multiple  `'name': 'xxx', 'shortVolume': xxx, 'longVolume': xxx`

then i need to save them into multiple txt files. For example EURUSD.txt contains name short volume and long volume, then another file GBPUSD.txt etc.

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understand it, all you need is a dynamic file location that is based on `name`

```py
# sample data
temp_data = [{'name': 'EURUSD', 'shortPercentage': 19, 'longPercentage': 81, 'shortVolume': 5241.27, 'longVolume': 22432.81, 'longPositions': 50708, 'shortPositions': 17864, 'totalPositions': 68572, 'avgShortPrice': 1.0925, 'avgLongPrice': 1.1103} ,{'name': 'GBPUSD', 'shortPercentage': 20, 'longPercentage': 80, 'shortVolume': 2319.04, 'longVolume': 9272.55, 'longPositions': 28637, 'shortPositions': 8572, 'totalPositions': 37209, 'avgShortPrice': 1.3014, 'avgLongPrice': 1.3248}, {'name': 'USDJPY', 'shortPercentage': 79, 'longPercentage': 21, 'shortVolume': 13172.25, 'longVolume': 3475.09, 'longPositions': 4530, 'shortPositions': 23878, 'totalPositions': 28408, 'avgShortPrice': 118.2402, 'avgLongPrice': 122.0914}, {'name': 'GBPJPY', 'shortPercentage': 78, 'longPercentage': 22, 'shortVolume': 1476.39, 'longVolume': 421.39, 'longPositions': 1820, 'shortPositions': 5248, 'totalPositions': 7068, 'avgShortPrice': 155.8968, 'avgLongPrice': 160.6128} ]

# base folder location
folder_loc = './'

for data in temp_data:
    # txt contains name short volume and long volume
    with open(f'{folder_loc}{data["name"]}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'{data["name"]} {data["shortVolume"]} {data["longVolume"]}')
```

[image]

PS: you can format the file contents and the file location as required

Comment: Your answer doesn't deal with the problem of the conversion from json to dict.

Comment: actually OP is converting `json` to `str`, so that part is not an issue, if OP asks for it, I will add info for that as well :)